# Is there a way to keep or steal back the jagged crown

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim after you give the jagged crown to Ulfric  is there a way to get it back, Or where does he keep it so you can steal it

Comment: On the PC you can just use the console to add one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to get the crown back without using mods or console commands. If you're playing on PC, you can use `player.additem 000da750 1` to give yourself a copy of the Jagged Crown, or you can install a mod that will let you craft a replica, such as the [Complete Crafting Overhaul Remade](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/49791/?).

Comment: How do you get mods for skyrim and install them

Comment: @jasonvalderrama you use the Skyrim Nexus or Steam Workshop (be warned, using Steam Workshop will lead to headaches if you ever want to uninstall a mod)

Answer (score -1):

You can pickpoket it back, then run out of the city store (the crown). Then pay for the crime, then pick it back up. It will be in a chest when you payed, they can't take it back.

Comment: you can't pickpocket it back.